# Decoding in php a text coded with encodeURI

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I use encodeURI and decodeURI to send French accented text from AS3 to my mysql database and get it back in AS3 and it works fine. 
Except that I also need to work on the text on the server where it's hopelessly mangled. php functions urldecode and rawurldecode only do part of the job. some coding remains.

Comment: example ? please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use: encodeURIComponent() on the js side and then use urldecode() on the php side?